# Por que me aparece que tablespace no existe

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c, oracle-19c

Estaba internando  completar un deber  donde me piden  que  cree un usuario llamado 'COMPRADOR'. El tableespace por defecto es 'COMPRAS' y se le asigna un mega en el tableespace COMPRAS y 0 de cuota en el tablespace SYSTEM. El tablespace temporal será TEMPORARY_DATA. Se le asigna un rol anterior. pero al momento de ejecutar me sale que la tablespace COMPRAS no existe
No se por que me salio asi ya que al momento de crearlo todo salio bien

```
CREATE TABLESPACE COMPRAS DATAFILE 'C:/OracleXE/ORADATA/XE/ COMPRAS.dbf' SIZE 5M;
ALTER TABLESPACE COMPRAS ADD DATAFILE 'COMPRAS1.dbf' SIZE 1M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

al crear el otro tablespace todo estaba correcto

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPORARY_DATA
TEMPFILE 'C:/OracleXE/ORADATA/XE/TEMPORARY_DATA.dbf' 
SIZE 5M 
AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

Pero cuando quise crear el usuario COMPRADOR me salio que no existia

```
CREATE USER C##COMPRADOR 
IDENTIFIED BY 654321 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE COMPRAS 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPORARY_DATA 
QUOTA 1M ON COMPRAS 
QUOTA 0 ON SYSTEM;
```

Comment: no sera que te falta iniciar sesion con el usuario con el que lo estas creando ademas vi que creaste el tablespace temporal ese solo dura el tiempo que dura una sesion iniciada hasta que la cierras

Comment: ¿No le sobra un espacio al datafile?